# Copperplate Gothic font not working in some versions of Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

Copperplate Gothic font not properly working in some versions of Firefox. whereas perfectly working in remaining browsers.
when I follow the instruction and Restart Firefox in Safe Mode, the problem does not happen in Safe Mode.
According to instruction for Troubleshoot and diagnose Firefox problems, If problem not occur in Safe Mode, it is most likely because of hardware acceleration. when I Turn off hardware acceleration, the problem is no longer happening, then hardware acceleration is likely the cause of this issue. 
How i can fix this issue for Firefox on deployed site without changing font.

Comment: Report the issue to Mozilla. Also without version info, all bets are off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have post question to mozilla firefox support(https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/930600). let see what they respond.